# spark-dataframe: Create new column with 2 boolean conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to mutate my dataframe based on 2 boolean conditions with a bitwise AND operation

```r
df %>% mutate(newVariable = ifelse(variable1 == "value1" & variable2 == "value2, variable3, NULL)
```

So in PySpark it tested this :

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df.withColumn("newVariable", func.when( \
     func.col("variable1") == "value1" & func.col("variable2") == "value2", \
     func.col("variable3")))
```

But I have an error

What is the correct way to create this kind of new variable with spark dataframe ?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remember about operator precedence. In Python `&` has a higher precedence than `==` so individual equality checks have to be parenthesized:

```
(func.col("variable1") == "value1") & (func.col("variable2") == "value2")
```

Otherwise expression is evaluated as:

```
(func.col("variable1") == ("value1" & func.col("variable2"))) == "value2"
```